# Playing in a campaign where two of the characters are pretty OP, and I have no idea what to do

Tags: dnd-5e

A whole bunch of my friends at school wanted to play some DnD 5e.  I was the only one with any previous experience, but only with 3.5, and the only other person with any experience had played one of the MMOs, and nothing else. 
Someone else wound up DMing, and we started up.

I probably should've noticed much earlier that the DM screwed up a lot of the rules, since we never did any initiative rolls (just used the Dex modifier and ordered everybody by that), and our rogue and one of our rangers were routinely able to one-shot just about every enemy in sight at 1st level.

This compounded another issue later on because the DM gave xp to those that dealt damage to the enemy that died, rather than evenly spreading it.

We're not even that far in (currently at our second boss), and already serious balance issues are coming up.  The ranger is now consistently dealing over 32 damage each attack b/c she went Beast Master, and the rogue has one-shot nearly every single enemy, exept bosses, with his 28 damage (minimum. He's usually gotten 30 damage on sneak attacks, because he's always hidden).

Currently I'm the third highest in XP, having a 700 XP Fighter, but the second highest (the ranger) has 1250 or so XP, and the rogue is 300 higher than her.

Am I just over-reacting or salty b/c of poor luck, or is there actually a serious problem here?

If there is a problem here, what can I do about it?

The DM doesn't seem to care...

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. This question needs a little focus. Is there a way for the main points to be broken down into paragraphs? Then, is it possible to narrow this to a question besides *What should I do?* like *What should I do when the DM doesn't follow the rules?* or *How can I politely leave an uncomfortable game?* (Similar questions have already been asked, though! Run a search!) Also, consider what advice a good answer to the question may offer then structure the question so that answers can *provide* that advice.  No matter what, though, thank you for participating!

Comment: This question's both very broad and a bit unclear. If you can narrow things down to a more concise, individual question, we may be able to help you better. It may also be prudent to elaborate a bit more on your own 5e experience, it seems you may be unfamiliar with how the system works (because usually Initiative is just a Dex check). Have you read or at least skimmed through the PHB yet?

Comment: Check out https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/why-was-my-question-closed-as-too-broad-unclear-or-opinion-based for tips on how to clarify your question.

Comment: I edited your question to break up the wall of text.  Please do as @HeyICanChan requested and provide a bit more scope to the question.  Please also edit to ensure that my attempted edit did not materially change the meaning of your question.  Please specify how many total characters there are, what their classes are, and what level each is.  (So far, we gather 1 Fighter, 1 Ranger, 1 Rogue.  Are there any more?)

Comment: Don't answer in comments.  Help the OP get the question clarified and reopened and then answer in answers.

Comment: Don't be put off by your question being closed in its current form. Many people here would like to help.